# Err apk application is closing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

My program writes random articles, this works on the screen, there is no problem with that.

After adding the application share button, the app closes directly. Can you review the codes? Thank you
I think the trouble is in the "public void share" part

this error did not exist before. The error has existed since I added the share (void share) codes. And I couldn't solve this error. I am waiting for help from you.

Main XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/k"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:text="Değiştir"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="random"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Kopyala"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="kopyala"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    
    <Button
        android:text="Share IT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="paylas"
        
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main java

```
package com.mycompany.myapp6;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    
    
    private TextView tw1;
    private Button btn1, btn2, bt;
    Random m;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tw1 = findViewById(R.id.tw1);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        bt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        
    }

    public void random(View view) {
        String colors[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.status);
        m = new Random();
        tw1.setText(colors[m.nextInt(colors.length)]);
    }
    
    public void paylas(String title, String content) {

        // Create an ACTION_SEND Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // Set the type of the content to "text"
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        // Adding extras to the intent (title & content) 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, title));
    }
    public void kopyala(View view) {
        String label = "Kopyalandı";
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, tw1.getText().toString());
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, label, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your button click listener?

Comment: <Button
        android:text="Share IT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="paylas"

Comment: Please Update the question with button action code.

Comment: I've already shared all the codes. There is no other code than these. I do not know english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You click action code will be  `paylas(View view)` instead  `paylas(String title, String content)`

So you need replace your code to following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ..............
 
    public void paylas(View view) {
        String title = "Share"; // you need get title in here.
        String content = tw1.getText().toString(); // this is new

        // Create an ACTION_SEND Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // Set the type of the content to "text"
        intent.setType("text/plain");

        // Adding extras to the intent (title & content) 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, title));
    }
}
```

**PS:**

If you need, get content from textView, you can do it this.

```
String text = tw1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But how do I set this to tw1. So I want to share the article in TextView.

Comment: you mean get content from TextView? i don't understand what do you need.

Comment: Yes true. id tw1. i want to share this

Comment: String text = tw1.getText().toString();. where do i write this